# How to use java.net.URI

Tags: java, standard-library

I've tried to use java.net.URI to manipulate query strings but I failed to even on very simple task like getting the query string from one url and placing it in another.

Do you know how to make this code below work

```
URI sample = new URI("test?param1=x%3D1");
URI uri2 = new URI(
            "http",
            "domain",
            "/a-path",
            sample.getRawQuery(),
            sample.getFragment());
```

Call to `uri2.toASCIIString()` should return: `http://domain/a-path?param1=x%3D1`
but it returns: `http://domain/a-path?param1=x%253D1` (double encoding)

if I use getQuery() instead of getRawQuery() the query string is not encoded at all and the url looks like this: `http://domain/a-path?param1=x=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second constructor will encode the query and fragment using URL encoding. But `=` is a legal URI character, so it will not encode that for you; and `%` is not a legal URI character, so it *will* encode it. That's exactly the opposite of what you want, in this case.

So, you can't use the second constructor. Use the first one, by concatenating the parts of the string together yourself.

Comment: Good explanation. So the URI interface is poorly designed (i hardly see any reason for the second constructor). Do you know any better URI class? Like joda-time that replace Date/Calendar class?

Comment: No, I don't... and `URI` is already a re-make of the older `java.net.URL` class, which has its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

Could you wrap the call to `getQuery()` with a call to `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String)`?

```
URI sample = new URI("test?param1=x%3D1");
URI uri2 = new URI(
        "http",
        "domain",
        "/a-path",
        URLEncoder.encode(sample.getQuery(), "UTF-8"),
        sample.getFragment());
```

Comment: Have you checked that?  `URLEncoder.encode(sample.getQuery())` is more or less equal to `sample.getRawQuery()` so you will end up with the same problem I had